# Am I stuck in the "Friends Zone"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I didn't pay much attention to Liara before, now on the citadel she says she wants to "be good friends". In a real life situation that usually means romance is out of the question.

Am I stuck in the "friend zone" now with Liara? Or is there a way to escape this?

I am referring to the dialog option here under **Closing the Deal**

http://www.gamesradar.com/mass-effect-3-romance-guide/?page=2

Instead, my options are

- Lets be friends
- Lets keep it professional

Comment: did you have the shadow broker DLC in me2 by any chance?

Comment: Brand new Shepard.

Answer (score 2):

I think that to get her to romance you have to visit every now and then.

As you said you didn't pay much attention to her before, why would she pay attention to you?

Comment: Because I saved the galaxy multiple times, that should be enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to visit her after each mission...maybe then she will romance you!

Answer (score 0):

You only get one chance for romance, it's not possible to "catch up". Looks like you are up for another playthrough :) And this time visit her after every mission ;)